# Jetty : websocket extended Custom Servlet

Tags: websocket, jetty

I am working on a Existing Jetty based WebSocket code .

In the existing code , in that servlet there are two methods implemented

```
1. public WebSocket doWebSocketConnect()
2.protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
```

As these are callback methods 
Could anybody please let me know what method is called first (I mean the method order )

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WebSocketServlet in jetty-7, and jetty-8 (note: this has changed in jetty-9), has a few requirements for you.

The [doWebSocketConnect(HttpServletRequest,String)](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/WebSocketFactory.Acceptor.html#doWebSocketConnect%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20java.lang.String%29) needs to be implemented by you to create a WebSocket object (of your design) based on the information you can find in the HttpServletRequest.  (such as host, paths, authentication, etc ...)

You can see an example of a Servlet in the test cases.
http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-websocket/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/helper/WebSocketCaptureServlet.java

This creates a [CaptureSocket](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-websocket/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/helper/CaptureSocket.java), stores it in the Servlet instance for tracking, and returns it.
The CaptureSocket just stores the incoming Messages so that the test cases can validate the expectations.
This isn't a particularly exciting Servlet/Socket impl.

An example of a few flavors of Echo sockets can also be found in the TestServer (also found in the test cases).
http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-websocket/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/TestServer.java#n53